# How can I select lines from a text string given certain criteria in python and add them to a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a large text file that I have read into a string called data.

I'm using CGI to generate an HTML5 form.

I need to select the lines that are formatted as follows from the string:

@*CountyName*:*Heading*

Here is an example:
@Algeria:Geography

I need to add the heading into a list of just headings and make them unique I've already done this with a list of countries but I didn't have to use criteria I used a line range instead. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting

data = open('factbook.txt')

countries = []
for index, text in enumerate(data):
    if 54 <= index <= 344:
        countries.append(text)
countries = [x[:-1] for x in countries]
countries = filter(None, countries)

headings = []
# Here is where I need help
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the way you are going is getting you the correct country names, I took a example of list you specified in the question:

```
In [73]: countries =[ "@Algeria:Geography", "@Greece:History", "@India:Culture", "@India:History"]
In [74]: countries = [x[:-1] for x in countries]
In [75]: countries
Out[75]: ['@Algeria:Geograph', '@Greece:Histor', '@India:Cultur', '@India:Histor']
```

Here you should do this to get countries

```
In [76]: countries = [x.split(':')[0][1:] for x in countries]
In [77]: countries
Out[77]: ['Algeria', 'Greece', 'India', 'India']
```

And similarly for the headings:

```
In [88]: countries =[ "@Algeria:Geography", "@Greece:History", "@India:Culture", "@India:History"]
In [89]: countries
Out[89]: {' Culture', ' History', 'Geography', 'History'}
```

For unique `list` use a `set`

```
In [89]: countries =[ "@Algeria:Geography", "@Greece:History", "@India:Culture", "@India:History"]
In [90]: countries = set([x.split(':')[1] for x in countries])
In [91]: countries
Out[91]: {'Culture', 'Geography', 'History'}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! This solves half of my problem. I already have the countries working because I just used a line range to grab them all from the text file they are all clustered together. My problem is grabbing all the lines that have the formatting @Country:Heading that are spread throughout the entire text file.

Comment: @Noah In that case you can look into `regex` to get the strings in the pattern you want. For more info have a look at : https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: Perfect, I'm relatively new to python regular expression pattern matching is just what I need. Thanks.